# Concatenating a series of strings into a single string within a Pandas Dataframe column (for each row)?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, concatenation

This is really throwing me for a loop. In a pandas dataframe (df) I have the following:

| date | News |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-03 | Some random event occurred today. |
| 2021-02-03 | We asked a question on Stack Overflow. |
| 2021-02-02 | The weather is nice. |
| 2021-02-02 | Hello. World. |

The date column is the index which is of the date format, and the News column is a string. What I want to do is to combine the duplicate dates and join or concatenate the News column, for example:

| date | News |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-03 | Some random event occurred today. We asked a question on Stack Overflow. |
| 2021-02-02 | The weather is nice. Hello. World. |

So far, I have:

df = df.groupby(['date']).agg({'News': list})

However, while this does combine the duplicated dates, it puts the string values in a list, or rather according to the errors I've been getting while trying to join them, into a series. At this point, I am completely lost and any hint/tip to lead me to the right pythonic way of doing this would be greatly appreciated!

PS: I would like to avoid using a loop if at all possible since this will need to parse through roughly 200k records multiple times (as a function). If it makes any difference, I'll be using TextBlob on the News column to perform sentiment analysis on.

Comment: `df.groupby('date')['News'].agg(' '.join)`.

Comment: Bloody hades, it was .join and not  : join  Thank you VERY much!!

Answer (score 0):

Quang Hoang answered the question perfectly! Although I'm not able to mark it as the answer sadly =(

> df.groupby('date')['News'].agg(' '.join). – Quang Hoang Feb 8 at 15:08